# multiple problems after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, mate

I have multiple problems after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I get random screen flickering that comes and goes. Amd stoney graphics on a hp laptop. All the solutions I have seen are for intel.  The only session that works out of 8 choices is the default gnome 42. I run Ubuntu studio 22.04 and Ubuntu 22.04 (dual boot) on my desktop with no issues. The on;y difference is mine was a clean install and hers was an upgrade.  I wish her version offered the kde.

Update***** this is an upgrade from an existing 20.04 with mate desktop. Mark this question as solved. I managed to get mate to work, still have some issues. But working

Comment: Did you try Ubuntu MATE 22.04? Or did you install MATE on top of regular Ubuntu? Also, I am not sure how KDE enters the story. Please edit the question to summarize the problem, and add the details of your hardware/graphics card.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 will be supported until 2025. You can continue to use it without upgrading.

Comment: One big long paragraph: difficult to read, so difficult to help. You may want to edit for readability.

Comment: Can you boot from a live USB and check if the issues occur there? If the live session is error-free, It might be easier to fresh install Ubuntu 22.04 than trying to find what caused the issue.

Comment: `I wish her version offered the kde.` -- Not sure what you meant. You can install Kubuntu 22.04 https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/

Comment: I have a Ubuntu 22.04 with kde plasma. That's what I meant . As I said this was not an install but an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstalled the mate package and rebooted. This worked for me.